# Cybersource rejects transaction with different values of purchaseTotals_grandTotalAmount

Tags: payment-processing

When perform a transaction through CyberSource it accepts some amounts while rejects some value of amounts. e.g if i put following amount, CyberSource will reject transaction with Error Code 203.

`request.put("purchaseTotals_grandTotalAmount", "1500");`

while if i change the amount to any of following, CyberSource will Accept the transaction

`request.put("purchaseTotals_grandTotalAmount", "7676");`
`request.put("purchaseTotals_grandTotalAmount", "324");`

i don't know what is the reason behind it. Is there any limitation or criteria for the amount or what.

Answer (score 1):

Cyber source inorder to simulate various scenratios, give  error codes based on the dollar amounts you pass to the service 
Based on the simulator that your service is tied up to you will get different responses.

https://www.cybersource.com/developers/test_and_manage/testing/simple_order_api/fdiglobal/soapi_fdiglobal_errors.html

Please see some of the above responses If NAshville Global simulator is configured as part of your apps cybersource account